# Xpath - how to select component by type and text

Tags: xpath

I have multiple data component on page
I need to select only one which have h2 text "Alert Me"

I have this, but it doesnt work. it selects only the data components, not h2 text

```
//*[@data-component='application-title'] |  h2[contains(.,'Alert Me')]
```

Comment: can you post your HTML code snippet. It will help us to help you

Comment: try only //h2[contains(.,'Alert Me')]

Answer (score 0):

If your `h2` element is not a root (I'm sure it's not) you should use below

```
//*[@data-component='application-title'] | //h2[contains(.,'Alert Me')]
```

to match both elements

*Note that you should specify `//` for `h2` also*